# Draw Bitmap under existing buttons and prevent overlap

Tags: android, android-studio, android-canvas, android-button, android-bitmap

I am trying to draw a Bitmap that covers a screen with grassy patches. The screen that I am drawing the Bitmap on already has a couple Buttons and TextViews. When I put the logic for drawing the Bitmap in the onDraw() method for the class (this class corresponds to the screen that already had Buttons and TextViews), the Bitmap gets drawn over the buttons. The result looks something like this:
[image]

The green grassy looking patches are the results of drawing the Bitmap. The Home button is the existing button on the page. As you can see, the green grassy patches that appear upon drawing the Bitmap overlap with the Home button. I don't want this to happen. I want the Home button and Money: $550 text to appear over the Bitmap.

**How would I go about doing this?**

Here is some of my code for reference:

**Screen.java**

```
private Bitmap grassPatches;
private List<Grass> grassLocations = new ArrayList<>();
private int mapSize = 75 * Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH / 1000;

public GameScreenDrawableView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    grassPatches = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.grass2);
    grassPatches = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(grassPatches, mapSize, mapSize, true);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 14; j++) {
            grassLocations.add(new Grass(grassPatches, j * mapSize +
                    Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 - 6 * mapSize,
                    i * mapSize + 100 * Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT / 1920, mapSize, mapSize));
        }
    }
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (int i = 0; i < grassLocations.size(); i++) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(grassLocations.get(i).getBitMap(),
                grassLocations.get(i).getX(),
                grassLocations.get(i).getY(),
                null);
    }
}
```

**Screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/game_screen_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#348C31"
    tools:context=".GameActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/h"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="472dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/m"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ex"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:onClick="ex"
        android:text="Home"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What is the grassLocations variable ?

Comment: Hey, I updated the post with information that answers your question.

Comment: How add `GameScreenDrawableView ` class in your activity?